# Update JArray in JObject JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, json.net

I have two files one is a json another is xml and I need to merge both, I decided to transform the xml in json after concat/merge.

```
{
    "Level1": {
        "Level2": [
            {
                "id": "Chart",
                "Box": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "value": "10"
                    },
                     {
                        "id": "2",
                        "value": "20"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The second Json:

```
{
    "Level1": {
        "Level2": [
            {
                "id": "NameApp",
                "Box": [
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "value": "90"
                    },
                     {
                        "id": "3",
                        "value": "50"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
{
    "Level1": {
        "Level2": [
            {
                "id": "Chart",
                "Box": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "value": "10"
                    },
                     {
                        "id": "2",
                        "value": "20"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "value": "90"
                    },
                     {
                        "id": "3",
                        "value": "50"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(pathXml);
        doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);

        string jsonTextXml = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

JSON code:

```
using (StreamReader readerJson = new StreamReader(pathJson))
        {
            jsonTextJson = readerJson.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Code for Merge:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(jsonTextJson);

JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(jsonTextXml);

JArray box1 = o1["Level1"]["Level2"]["Box"][0] as JArray;

JArray box2 = o2["Level1"]["Level2"]["Box"][0] as JArray;

box1 = new JArray(box1.Concat(box2));

o1["Level1"]["Level2"]["Box"][0].Replace(box1);
```

When I wannt get the box1, I have this error: Object reference not set to an object instance.

I tested with this another way..

```
JArray box1 = o1["Level1"]["Level2"][0]["Box"] as JArray;
```

What is wrong?

Finally this was my solution SOLUTION:

```
 public string joinJson(string jsonFinal, string jsonTemp)
    {

        JObject jsonMaster = JObject.Parse(jsonFinal);

        JObject jsonForMerge = JObject.Parse(jsonTemp);

        foreach (var element in jsonForMerge["Level1"]["Level2"])
        {
           string pathElement = element.Path;
           string component = pathElement.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Last();

           if (element.HasValues && !component.Equals("id"))
            {
                JArray contentTemp = jsonForMerge["Level1"]["Level2"][component] as JArray;
                JArray contentFinal = jsonMaster["Level1"]["Level2"][0][component] as JArray;

                contentFinal = new JArray(contentFinal.Concat(contentTemp));
                jsonMaster["Level1"]["Level2"][0][component].Replace(contentFinal);
            }
        }

        return jsonMaster.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to do it the other way round. Deserialize your json to classes (this may help: [JsonUtils](http://jsonutils.com/)).

```
    public class Box
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Level2
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Box> Box { get; set; }
    }

    public class Level1
    {
        public List<Level2> Level2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Level1 Level1 { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the structure of both of your json strings.
Now deserialize:

```
RootObject rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json1);
RootObject rootObject2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json2);
```

Now you can iterate over your objects and 'merge' it and then serialize them again.

```
foreach (var level in rootObject2.Level1.Level2)
{
    rootObject1.Level1.Level2.Add(level);
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject1);
```

Of course you could merge your objects deeper than that (for each box in Box to Level2).

Comment: One question If I want to get in this example, the Level 2, How can I do that? Didn't work in this way:  JArray contentK = _jsonMaster["Level1"]["Level2"] as JArray;